# Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found"

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

I get the following error when trying to run a **PHP** script that access local **MongoDB**:

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found".

I have setup apache (2.4.23), along with PHP (5.6.25) and MongoDB (2.4.14)
and a MongoDB driver (1.1.0).
**Everything seems to be working from the command line** (cli), but when I try
to access the DB via the web I get an error saying "

> Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found".

I am aware that php.ini has a special configuration file for apache
(/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini), and **I have enabled the mongodb.so extension**
there. However, I am still getting that error.
I double checked that php is actually reading the configuration from there:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php5/apache2 Loaded
>
> Configuration File /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini Loaded

According to the MongoDB website (
https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-php),
MongoDB (2.4) is compatible with mongoDB php Driver version 1.1.
Again, from the command line, my test script works:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
    
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:28124");
```

Any Ideas?!?!?!?

Comment: Try `new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager(...)` (note the leading backslash). This probably won't change anything but it's worth a shot

Comment: Also, did you restart Apache?

Comment: \ or not \ doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Apache restart doesn't help

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is apache related issue. It simply doesn't add the extension. Even though I am editing the right configuration file (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini). I'll try to downgrade to 2.2 and see if that makes any difference

Comment: Can this be related somehow to my php installation? I wasn't able to compile it with the apxs flag

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The issue was that I didn't compile php with apxs support. Once I added that (./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2) everything was working properly.

Comment: where did you add this?

Comment: please breif the answer!